# Fail to add WHERE constraint on result of nested query - ERROR 42883 in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, subquery

This seems like a pretty straight forward nested query to me - but clearly there is something that I am missing entirely.

SETTING:

- I have two tables `ccod` and `psc`.
- `psc` has col `company_number`, which I want to be matched on
- `ccod.company_number_1` or `ccod.company_number_2`.

given that the tables are pretty big, I use some prior knowledge to reduce the number of company numbers to be matched:

- company numbers cannot be nulls
- company numbers must be 8 char long
- `psc.company_number` is clean and contains only 8-char long strings.
- `ccod.company_number_1` or `ccod.company_number_2` contains a lot of junk.
- `ccod.company_number_1` or `ccod.company_number_2` can both be null, both contain a string or either contain one.
- I don't care about duplicates for now.

Plus

- use `UNION ALL` to create 1 single column as result of the joining the two columns of `ccod` - aliasing it to `stacked_company_numbers`.

so:

```
SELECT *
INTO ccod_psc
FROM psc
WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT psc.company_number)
          in
      (SELECT DISTINCT stacked_company_numbers
       FROM (SELECT company_number_1
             FROM ccod
             WHERE company_number_1 is not null
             UNION ALL
             SELECT company_number_2
             FROM ccod
             WHERE company_number_2 is not null) AS stacked_company_numbers
       WHERE char_length(stacked_company_numbers::text) = 8);
```

```
[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: text = record
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 86
```

Now the words of this error are pretty self-explanatory, but I have no idea how to fix it, and have tried a lot of other answers related to error 42883, but unsuccessfully.

Thanks for any bit of help.

-- EDIT:

I also found a way to make my query work:

```
SELECT *
INTO ccod_psc
FROM psc
WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT psc.company_number)
          in
      (SELECT company_number_1
       FROM ccod
       WHERE company_number_1 is not null
       UNION -- this takes cares of the duplicates.
       SELECT company_number_2
       FROM ccod
       WHERE company_number_2 is not null) AS stacked_company_numbers
WHERE char_length(stacked_company_numbers::text) = 8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think two `left join`s is more efficient:

```
SELECT p.*
INTO ccod_psc c 
FROM psc p LEFT JOIN
     ccod c1
     ON p.company_number = c1.company_number_1 LEFT JOIN
     ccod c2
     ON p.company_number = c2.company_number_2 AND
        c1.company_number_1 IS NULL
WHERE c1.company_number_1 IS NOT NULL OR
      c2.company_number_2 IS NOT NULL
```

The advantage of this approach is that this can use indexes on `ccod(company_number_1)` and `ccod(company_number_2)`.

EDIT:

If there can be duplicates in `ccod`, then `exists` might have better performance:

```
SELECT p.*
INTO ccod_psc c 
FROM psc p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ccod c1
              WHERE p.company_number = c1.company_number_1
             ) OR
     EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ccod c2
              WHERE p.company_number = c2.company_number_2
             ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks! where do you define the alias `stacked_company_numbers` in the first solution? I also get an error for the `p.*` `unable to resolve symbol p` (which disappears when I remove the `into---`.

Comment: @TytireRecubans . . . I found your query hard to follow and thought that was a column in the second table.  In any case, I fixed the query.  You are just looking for a match.

Comment: Thanks! One thing i dont get - why `AND c1.company_number_1 IS NULL` in the first solution?

Comment: @TytireRecubans . . . It is not strictly needed.  It just matches to the second table only when the first match doesn't go through.  With `LEFT JOIN`s, I don't think there is any performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

I do suspect that `exists` does what you want:

```
select p.*
from psc p
where 
    char_length(p.company_numbers::text) = 8
    and exists (
        select 1
        from ccod c
        where p.company_number in (c.company_number_1, c.company_number_2)
    )
```

The query pulls out records from `psc` whose `company_number` are 8 characters long and can be found in either `company_number_1` or `company_number_2` in table `ccod`.

Comment: Thanks! The problem with this logic is that I want to apply the char_length on the c.company_number_1, c.company_number_2 columns as there is a lot of junk there. I'll edit my q.

Comment: @TytireRecubans: ok. If `p.company_numbers` is clean, then you do not need additional processing on `company_number_1` and  company_number_2`, since we are looking for an exact match.

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to omit the NULL from `in (c.company_number_1, c.company_number_2)`?